# The boy the girl the man saw kissed jumped

Tags: grammar, clauses, subjects

My Japanese friend asked me to help him translate this sentence but I cannot understand it.
Can someone explain the grammar of this?

Comment: Agreed, this is an intentionally complex sentence that even native English speakers would have trouble with. Could the main subject-verb-object be: "The girl jumped"? and an untangling of the sentence be: "the girl (that) the man saw (who was) kissed (by) the boy.. (this girl) jumped"?

Comment: @rajah9 Try to understand it from the iniside working outwards. The girl is the girl the man saw. So we may simplify the sentence by removing "the man saw". It is now "The boy the girl kissed jumped". The boy is the boy the girl kissed. Simplify by removing "the girl kissed". We're left with "The boy jumped". It's the boy, not the girl, who jumped. The man saw the girl; the girl kissed the boy; the boy jumped.

Comment: It's just wrong.

Comment: I agree with the main part of the technical analysis by @RosieF. However, putting together the logical pieces still doesn't make sense. Even if it was the boy who jumped (which it has to be), the intervening pieces turn the complete sentence into nonsense. This makes sense: *The boy the girl saw kissed jumped.* This also makes sense: *The girl the man saw kissed jumped*. The combination of both of those does not make sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah, are you taking "kissed" as a complement of "saw"? So that "The boy the girl saw kissed" is a NP with the structure of "The bridge the manager saw built"? I took "saw" as the inner relative clause's verb and "kissed" as the outer relative clause's verb. Putting brackets around each NP: [The boy [the girl the man saw] kissed] jumped.